# Add class to div when another element is hovered and remove when not hovered

Tags: jquery

I added a class using jQuery to an element that only appears when a certain menu-item is hovered over.

This is the code I used:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#sfm-sidebar .sfm-menu-level-0 li a").hover(function(){
    jQuery("#cursor").addClass("hover");
});
});
```

The reason why I'm using the jQuery is because these elements aren't related to one another at all. This code works but then the only problem is that the class doesn't get removed when I move away from the menu-item.

I figured I needed to add a remove class function perhaps with an if/else statement but I'm not sure how to entirely write that script.

Any assistance would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to handle the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#sfm-sidebar .sfm-menu-level-0 li a").on('mouseenter',function() {
    jQuery("#cursor").addClass("hover");
  }).on('mouseleave',function(){
    jQuery("#cursor").removeClass("hover");
  });
});
```